# PHP initialize multimensional arrays before increment

Tags: php, arrays, warnings, declaration, multi-dimensional-scaling

I have to perform a big code fix in an old php project.
The issue is the following: I have a number statements where the code tries to add integers to non-initialized multimensional arrays, like this:

```
$array_test['first']['two']['three'] += 10;
```

But **$array_test** is declared just like this:

```
$array_test = array();
```

This situation gives me a lot of warnings in the project cause this code pattern happens like 16k times.

Is there any way to solve this like adding a statement like this:

```
if (!isset($array_test['first']['two']['three'])) 
{
         $array_test['first']['two']['three']=0;
}
```

and then

```
$array_test['first']['two']['three'] += 10;
```

But I would like to do it in only one code line (for both statement, the if isset and the increment) in order to make a big and safe replace in my project.

Can someone help me?
Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: You're on the right track but your `isset` is looking too far ahead. `$array_test` doesn't even have `['first']` set yet but you're checking several ways down. 
Everything needs to be init'd step by step. `$array_test['first'] = array();` and then `$array_test['first']['two'] = array();` and so on. Once all levels are declared, then you can init to 0 `$array_test['first']['two']['three']=0;` and your `+=` should work.

Comment: I disagree with the above comment.  You do not need to instantiate all parent levels.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not yet (and probably won't ever) have a "null coalescing addition operator.

From PHP7.0, you can avoid the `isset()` call by null coalescing to 0. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/26HWD)

```
$array_test['first']['two']['three'] = ($array_test['first']['two']['three'] ?? 0) + 10;
```

If below PHP7 (all the way down to at least PHP4.3), you can use an inline (ternary) condition. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/3407c)

```
$array_test['first']['two']['three'] = (isset($array_test['first']['two']['three']) ? $array_test['first']['two']['three'] : 0) + 10;
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this version compatible also with PHP versions < 7?

Comment: The null coalescing operator was born in PHP7.  If your boss won't upgrade to a supported version of PHP, them that you are going to quit and find a job where you can develop modern programming skills.